# Criando string no PHP

Tags: php, string

É possível criar no PHP uma variável do tipo `string` que contenha tantos *bytes*, ou seja, definidos pelo programador?

Exemplo em C:

```
char string[20];
```

Nesse caso, string sempre terá 20 bytes, independente do que estiver armazenado nela.

---

Resolução com str_pad(args):

```
$str = str_pad("HelloWorld", 20, "\0");
```

Essa linha, garante que `$str` tenha 20 bytes, ou seja, se `HelloWorld` não tem 20 bytes, ele preenche com \0 o restante.

Comment: Você quer um tipo novo ou apenas fazer que a string tenha uma quantidade fixa de caracteres?

Comment: Quero que ela tenha uma quantidade fixa de caracteres

Comment: No php não tem essas coisas que tem no C. É diretão mesmo : `$variavel = 'minha_string'`. Como já disse em outra resposta: _O php é uma linguagem de tipagem fraca_.

Comment: Não, mas você pode fazer um substr de 20 caracteres que seria uma solução

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Se quiser só garantir o tamanho crie e use uma função que faça isto sempre que quiser garantir o tamanho:

```
function fixedSTring($txt, $length) {
    $length = max($length, strlen($length);
    return str_pad(substr($txt, 0, $length), $length);
}
```

Se quiser algo garantido e automático, basta criar um novo tipo, uma nova classe que além de guardar uma *string*, guarde o tamanho fixo dela e aplique o critério acima. Algo assim (não está completo e e testado, é só uma base)

```
final class FixedString {
    private $txt = '';
    public function __construct($txt, $length) {
        $length = max($length, strlen($length));
        $this->txt = str_pad(substr($txt, 0, $length), $length);
    }
    public function __toString() {
        return $this->txt;
    }
}
```

Uso:

```
$texto = new FixedString("teste", 20);
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/String/BuildFixedSize.php).

Evidentemente precisa fazer melhores verificações, ter mais métodos que ajudem o trabalho. Fazer um tipo novo deve ser muito bem pensado. Eu não faria o preenchimento e corte da *string* de forma automática assim, tem maneiras melhores de lidar com isto, mas a pergunta não entra em detalhes.

Comment: Beleza. Você me deu até uma idéia. Vou fazer um repo no git :)

Comment: @WallaceMaxters obrigado pela edição, pode melhorar ou faça uma classe na sua resposta.

Comment: da pra colocar o substr no overload __toString também da para colocar overloads de __get e __set para alterar os valores

Comment: @AdirKuhn sim, dá para melhorar bastante, mas como eu disse, só fiz uma base, não tive a intenção de fazer a classe completa.

Comment: Dá pra implementar `ArrayAccess` para acessar cada parte da string como um índice

Comment: @WallaceMaxters sim, tem várias formas de otimizar isto. Dá para fazer todo o esquema da *string* por completo e não usar uma *string* interna. Precisa ver se compensa.

Comment: Muito brigado, a função str_pad(args) resolveu meu problema.

Comment: Eu achei mesmo que o problema era bem mais simples do que parecia.

Comment: Entendi, @bigown. A questão não é "o que dá pra fazer", mas "o que ele vai precisar"

Comment: evite funções "non-binary safe".. strlen() não suporta multibyte e retornaria valores diferentes para caracteres multibyte. Sugiro mudar para mb_strlen() tal como qualquer outra função que não suporte multibyte, deve trocar pelo seu equivalente das funções MBString.

Comment: Postei a minha resolução na pergunta, utilizando a função str_pad(args) usada pelo @bigown na sua resposta. Se algo estiver faltando, por favor me corrijam.

Answer (score 3):

O PHP é uma linguagem de tipagem fraca. Não é possível definir um tamanho inicial para a `string` - pelo menos não nativamente.

O que dá pra fazer são funções ou classes, que irão fazer esse trabalho.

Exemplo:

```
function fixed_string($string, $length) {
    return substr(sprintf("%' {$length}s", $string), 0, $length);
}

var_dump(fixed_string('oi ', 20));

var_dump(fixed_string('oi oi oi oi oi oi oi oi oi', 20));
```

Resultado:

```
string '                 oi ' (length=20)

string 'oi oi oi oi oi oi oi' (length=20)
```

## Atualização

Criei uma classe aperfeiçoada, baseada na resposta do @Maniero.

Veja que nela implemento `ArrayAccess` e alguns recursos para identificação da codificação:

[FixedString no GitHub](https://github.com/wallacemaxters/fixed-string)

Exemplo:

```
$string = new FixedString('Oi', 2, 'utf-8');
```

Comment: isso não é uma gambiarra

Comment: Vou tirar o trecho. Esses termos as vezes são apelativos

Comment: Isto não garante nada, funciona se a pessoa usar direitinho, ou seja, é gambiarra. Nada contra a resposta, até upei ela, a minha também é gambi na primeira parte. E a segunda está meia-boca.

Comment: @WallaceMaxters o link para o FixedString no Github está quebrado. Poderia verificar? obrigado!